# Same Keyframe animation with different name not running on other identically structured element

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have two sliders containing brand logos, moving right to left like in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8tGhugAces&ab_channel=Eazy2Code).
While for now, by chance, both sliders contain the same number of logos and thus the *width* *multiplier (half the number of logos per slider)* at the `100% keyframe translateX calc()` is the same, in the future the number of logos per slider may change and the multiplier accordingly. Therefore, to be able to easily change the multiplier if needed, **I tried to assign a differently named same keyframe animation to the two sliders**, namely:
*animation for slider 1:*

```
@keyframes rightToLeftScrollSlider1 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(calc(-100px*9.5)); /*multiplier may change in future!*/
    }
};
```

*animation for slider 2:*

```
@keyframes rightToLeftScrollSlider2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(calc(-100px*9.5)); /*multiplier may change in future!*/
    }
};
```

**The two sliders are structurally identical html div elements without any styling differences**, but unexpectedly only the animation assigned to the first slider is visible, with logos moving correctly like in the tutorial, whereas **the second slider stands still,** *although upon inspection its animation is being played.*
**If I assign only the first or the second animation to both sliders, it works.** However, this cannot be a long-term solution, the multiplier being susceptible to change based on the number of logos, which in turn is likely to vary in time.

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: I believe this is caused by a small syntax error, you have semicolons after the keyframes, that is not correct CSS so the second definition will not be taken on. Please confirm that this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but no: removing the semicolons does not solve the problem.